# configuring different color for different theme

Tags: android, android-theme

I am trying to config DayNight theme.

My **values/style.xml** and (**values-night/style.xml**) is:

```
<resources>
  <!-- Base application theme. -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
  </style>
  <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>
  <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
</resources>
```

and **colors.xml** is:

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#008577</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#00574B</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#D81B60</color>
    <color name="lSun">#ff9800</color>
    <color name="lMoon">#3f51b5</color>
    <color name="lMoonDark">#4f9fbd</color>
</resources>
```

Now, like,

```
 <TextView
              android:id="@+id/mr_icon"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_below="@+id/longi"
              android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
              android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
              android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/sunset"
              android:fontFamily="@font/weathericons"
              android:paddingTop="-2dp"
              android:text="@string/moonrise"
              android:textAlignment="center"
              android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Menu"
              android:textColor="@color/lMoon"
              android:textSize="14sp" />
```

here, I want `@color/lMoon` for light theme, and `@color/lMoonDark` for dark theme.

How I can achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

Make two styles and give the required style to the TextView.

```
<style name="MyTextView" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
   <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
   <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
   <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
   <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>

<TextView
          style="@style/MyTextView"
          android:id="@+id/mr_icon"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below="@+id/longi"
          android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
          android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/sunset"
          android:fontFamily="@font/weathericons"
          android:paddingTop="-2dp"
          android:text="@string/moonrise"
          android:textAlignment="center"
          android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Menu"
          android:textColor="@color/lMoon"
          android:textSize="14sp" />
```